# WGET command in CMD statement on Dockerfile doesn't work

Tags: docker, dockerfile, wget

i wrote a simple Dockerfile file to build a docker image.
The Dockerfile install some packages during the Docker image building process and then the docker image download a file from a specific URL using thew wget command on the CMD statement (because i need the file will be downloaded every time i run the docker image).
But unfortunatly it doesn't work and the file wasn't downloaded.
This is my simple Dockerfile:

```
# The Docker Image starts from the standard Ubuntu docker image (latest version)
FROM ubuntu:latest

LABEL Autor:="Christian Marinelli"
LABEL version="1.0"

# This will install the i386 architecture and then all the packages needed for TSX
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y libc6-i386 libstdc++5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386
RUN apt-get install -y ncompress unrar psmisc bzip2 wget
RUN apt-get install -y libgcc1 libbz2-1.0 libxrender1 libxext6 libx11-6 libxau6 libxdmcp6 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 zlib1g libexpat1 libxcb1

# Download the latest installer
WORKDIR /opt
CMD ["wget", "--user", "AAAAAAA", "--password", "BBBBB", "https://CCCCCCC.com/repository/DDDDDDD/20233000/dist/64bit/INSTALLER.exe"]
```

I tried to run the same command in the CLI in the Docker environment and it works, the internet connectivity is OK and the wget command is present in the OS. Can anyone hep me understanding where there is the error or debugging the run phase of the docker image?
Thanks in adavance

I tried to run the same command in the CLI in the Docker environment and it works, the internet connectivity is OK and the wget command is present in the OS.

Comment: "Didn't work" isn't sufficiently technical. Look at `docker logs` and see what happened. We have no idea. For all we know that's just a 404 response.

Comment: Also, exactly how you're quoting/escaping matters; quoting things for shell and quoting things for JSON are very different. I've seen people take a working shell command `--password '%@$hi'` and write `"--password", "'%@$hi'"`, for example, and that's obviously wrong but when you change your password to `BBBBB` we can't tell if you made that kind of error. We don't need/want your _real_ password, but we do need something that fails _the exact same way_, and enough logs from your code "not working" to recognize whether what we have _is_ failing the same way vs failing from an unrelated cause.

Comment: I think i found the problem, i run the docker with docker run --name=c01 -d -it bb41264f413e where bb41264f413e is the docker image ID and from the logs i saw the file was donwloaded but unfortunalty the docker exited at the end. How can i mantain it active at the end of the download?

Comment: A Docker container is a wrapper around a single _process_.  As you've written it, that process is the `wget`, and when the process exits (the file is downloaded) the container exits.  Do you want to make this into a `RUN` command so the file is baked into the image, and set the `CMD` to something else?  (What is the thing the container should actually do?)

Comment: @DavidMaze because the file that is downloaded from the wget command can change one/two/three times a day so i need a way to downloaded it at the docker startup. If i download it with the RUN command during the image building process it will remain the same "forever" and i will have to regenerate the image everytime